# sqlite syntax error when there shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I was writing a personall wrapper for sqlite3, the code looks something like this:

```js
export class sqlite3Wrapper {
  #connection;
  #run;
  #get;

  constructor(dbName: string) {
    this.#connection = new sqlite3.Database(dbName);
    this.#run = promisify(this.#connection.run.bind(this.#connection));
    this.#get = promisify(this.#connection.get.bind(this.#connection));
  }

  async insert(table: string, { fields, values, object, updateOnDuplicate = false }: { fields?: string | string[]; values?: any | any[]; object?: { [key: string]: any }; updateOnDuplicate?: boolean }): Promise<any> {
    let f = object ? Object.keys(object) : fields;
    let v = object ? Object.values(object) : values;

    if (!f || !v) throw new Error("Fields can't be empty");
    if (!Array.isArray(v)) {
      v = [values as any];
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(f)) {
      f = [fields as string];
    }

    if (f.length !== v.length) throw new Error("Fields and values must be the same length");

    let str = "";
    let updateStr = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
      updateStr += `${f[i]} = `;

      if (typeof v[i] === "string") {
        str += `"${v[i]}"`;
        updateStr += `"${v[i]}"`;
      } else {
        str += v[i];
        updateStr += v[i];
      }

      if (i < v.length - 1) {
        str += ", ";
        updateStr += ", ";
      }
    }

    return await this.#run(`INSERT INTO ${table} (${f.join(", ")}) VALUES (${str})${updateOnDuplicate ? " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " + updateStr : ""}`);
  }
}
```

I have other function as well but I cut them out to save space.

When I'm calling this, I do it like this:

```js
  const obj = { name: "hii", tetst: "thisis a test" };
  const theJsonFile = JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.log(theJsonFile);
await db.insert("jsonTest", { fields: ["id", "value"], values: ["3", theJsonFile] });
```

it works if instead of `theJsonFile` I pass a string, but when I try to do a stringified object, it gives this error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "name": syntax error] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}
```

there shoudn't be anything wrong with the connection because the other functions work just fine.

Comment: I tried passing the `theJsonFile` var as a string as well but it still gives the same unwanted result

Comment: Can you log the SQL string and add that to the question?

Comment: You shouldn't substitute variables directly into the SQL. You should use a prepared statement with placeholders, and put the variables into a parameter list.

Comment: You have a JSON string, it uses double quotes around its embedded strings. But you're putting double quotes around the values, without escaping the embedded quotes. So the quotes in the JSON terminate the quotes that delimit the value.

Comment: This is why you should use a prepared statement.